# Login with facebook dialog showing Invalid access token error message

Tags: java, android, facebook-login

[image]

When try to login with facebook i see this screen. I am unable to login, but this issue is not with all facebook ids. With some Ids i am able to login successfully.

What i tried: Add facebook tester account in the facebook developer console.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved. It was nothing just facebook tester account which i added to facebook developer console took some time to save. So after some time its working fine.